# Azure Function Username and Password

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I noticed, after creating a publish profile for an Azure Function, that the profile includes a username and password, neither of which I supplied.  I don't even know what the password is.  The username is merely the name of the Function App, prefixed with a dollar sign.  Where did these come from?  Are they something I need to know more about?

I'm partly curious, but partly wondering if this has anything to do with a separate issue where my Function App runs locally just fine, but doesn't run once published to Azure.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the App-level deployment credentials. The credentials for each app are generated automatically at app creation. You can find the password or reset the password on Azure portal. Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-configure-credentials) for more details.
[image]